# Website Scraping using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am struggling with scraping some data from a website. I have stepped through and for some reason the Question.className does not match what I have and what I have checked on the inspector on the web page. When I say match, nothing seems to be assigned. I have just started to look at data scraping and would appreciate any tips. I haven't included all code as the below code is the where the error occurs. Thanks in advance and apologise if this has been asked before but I couldn't find anything after having a search so thought I would post.

The URL is - https://stackoverflow.com

```
Range("A3").Value = "Question id" 'put heading across the top of row 3
Range("B3").Value = "Votes"
Range("C3").Value = "Views"
Range("D3").Value = "Person"

Dim QuestionList As IHTMLElement
Dim Questions As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Question As IHTMLElement
Dim RowNumber As Long
Dim QuestionId As String
Dim QuestionFields As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim QuestionField As IHTMLElement
Dim votes As String
Dim views As String
Dim QuestionFieldLinks As IHTMLElementCollection

Set QuestionList = html.getElementById("question-mini-list")
Set Questions = QuestionList.Children

RowNumber = 4

For Each Question In Questions
'if this is the tag containing the question details, process it
If Question.className = "question-summary narrow" Then
'first get and store the question id in first column
QuestionId = Replace(Question.ID, "question-summary-", "")
Cells(RowNumber, 1).Value = CLng(QuestionId)

'get a list of all of the parts of this question, and loop over them
Set QuestionFields = Question.all

For Each QuestionField In QuestionFields
'if this is the question's votes, store it (get rid of any surrounding text)

    If QuestionField.className = "votes" Then
        votes = Replace(QuestionField.innerText, "votes", "")
        votes = Replace(votes, "vote", "")
        Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value = Trim(votes)
    End If

    'likewise for views (getting rid of any text)
    If QuestionField.className = "views" Then
        views = QuestionField.innerText
        views = Replace(views, "views", "")
        views = Replace(views, "view", "")
        Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value = Trim(views)
    End If

    'if this is the bit where author's name is ...
    If QuestionField.className = "started" Then
    'get a list of all elements within, and store the text in the second one
        Set QuestionFieldLinks = QuestionField.all
        Cells(RowNumber, 4).Value = QuestionFieldLinks(2).innerHTML
    End If
Next QuestionField
'go on to next row of worksheet
RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
End If
Next
```

Comment: Can't give much help without knowing what's on the page and which section of your code is the issue.  Here's a good tutorial (there are 4 parts in [the playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrPEAljQjRM&list=PLNIs-AWhQzcl3xKvF8sVL4sWRWICj_clM).)

Comment: Apologies for not including the URL. This has now been included. Thanks @ashleedawg for the link.

Comment: You want to practice VBA or solve a problem. If solving your issue is your prime motto then either use Python with Scrapy/BeautifulSoup or simply a chrome extension like Webscraper.io. Hope it helps !

Comment: Question.className may be returning 1 class at a time. Try searching for in the string rather than exact match using InStr function. Also, did you tried adding watch on Question.classname?

Comment: @jainashish thanks for the reply. I will try using the Instr function and see if this works. I am practicing VBA rather than solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It should fetch you the required fields:

```
Sub GetInformation()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As HTMLDivElement, URL$, R&

    URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/"

    With Http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each post In Html.getElementsByClassName("question-summary")
        R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = Split(post.getAttribute("id"), "-")(2)
        Cells(R, 2) = Split(post.querySelector(".votes span").getAttribute("title"), " ")(0)
        Cells(R, 3) = Split(post.querySelector(".views span").getAttribute("title"), " ")(0)
    Next post
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft XML, v6.0
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: I could not understand what you meant by `person` as the fourth field in your question.

Comment: Plus 1 and I think they mean person is  .querySelector(".started-link ~ a").innerText

Comment: @TheRunner83, So if you wish to get the persons' name, just create another line using `post.querySelector(".started-link + a").innerText` or the one suggested by QHarr.

Comment: @SIM thanks for this. Works great. Ok great. I will try this for the persons name. Thanks again